# Can not serve my Laravel project that cloned from my Bitbucket repository

Tags: laravel, bitbucket

I pushed my Laravel project to my bitbucket repository and cloned on another Loptop when I write `php artisan serve` It says:


**`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\MyProject/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\MyPc
\Desktop\MyProject\artisan on line 18`**

Comment: you gave us a lot of information, so expect a lot of help now :)

Comment: Please, check the rules, how to form a question. Why are you sharing with us that your project is not running?? There is no question, no data.

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make sure that php, composer and a plethora of other php extensions are installed on your other node. also after cloning you'll have to copy the `.env.example` to `.env` and change some values, run `compser install`, `php artisan key:generate` and `php artisan storage:link`. Usually that's enough. Don't forget to setup your webserver to serve your new app.

**UPDATE**
Run the migrations: `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Usually you also have to migrate, otherwise you won't have tables in your database.